# Sqlite raw query

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I want to do a rawquery and sort the result according to some alphanumeric value. Like I have column ItemId which contains values like A0001,A0002,A0036,B0085 etc.

```
String query="select S_PriceP,ItemId,ItemName from PDAProduct where ItemId<=A0001 and ItemId>=A0099 order by ItemId";
```

Is there any way I can achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [rawQuery](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#rawQuery%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D%29).

```
String query="select S_PriceP,ItemId,ItemName from PDAProduct where ItemId<=A0001 and 
ItemId>=A0099 order by ItemId"; 
Cursor objCursor = objSQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(query, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

With the little info you have given us, my best answer would be to look at [SQLiteDatabase docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html)... in particular, you want one of the `query` methods.   If you were to post some of the code you have tried we might be able to find what you're missing.